# Autocreating transaction in DAO - spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I have dao extending generic dao doing base action like save, get, delete and update Object in DB.

On every action I must manually start and commit transaction. I trying find way to do it automatically.

This is implementation of generic dao:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getCurrentSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

private Class<T> type;

public GenericDaoImpl() {
    Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
    type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(final T t) {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(t);
    tr.commit();
}
}
```

when I remove this two lines:

```
Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
tr.commit();
```

It will not work. I think that @Transactional annotations handle transaction for me.

This is my bean config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- this is the dao object that we want to make transactional -->
    <bean id="testDao" class="com.springapp.mvc.dao.GenericDaoImpl" abstract="true"/>



    <!-- the transactional advice  -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

What should I do to constrain on spring transaction management?

Comment: which method calls your save method? it could be a proxy problem. Annotations will only work if you invoke your method through a proxy.

Comment: @ArnaudPotier I have Service, In service concrete dao where I call methods. That concrete dao extends my GenericDao. 

I first heard about proxy so it possible I'm not using it. Can you tell me more about it?

Comment: I added a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does provided you have the proper configuration,

If you are using a proxy to access your bean methods, this way as:

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao dao;

    public void someMethod() {
        dao.save(myObject)
    }

    //bla bla
}
```

provided you have `<context:annotation-config/>` in your XML config, it should autowire your Dao and call the save method.

But it won't be wrapped in the transaction:     To handle transactions through annotation, Spring uses a proxy wrapping your method calls. you can see these calls in your IDE in the debug mod.
The huge stack calls with "$proxy... " are created by spring and its proxys.

`<tx:annotation-driven>` specifies that spring should use annotations to manage transactions.
However, it needs a proxy to wrap them around method calls.
Therefore, you need to add the following line to your XML: `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I add <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> to my xml but still spring don't auto handle transactions.